# Passing const as 'this' argument error when calling std::sort on a list of structures

Tags: linux, qt, sorting, std, cross-compiling

I have a rather large `struct` called `Journey`:

```
typedef struct Journey
{
    /**
      * @brief The InfoText struct is a container for storing messages (short and long) that are found
      * inside a journey's <InfoTextLists/> as <InfoText/> elements
      */
    typedef struct InfoText
    {
        QString shortMsg;
        QString longMsg;

        InfoText(QString shortMsg, QString longMsg)
        {
            this->shortMsg = shortMsg;
            this->longMsg = longMsg;
        }

        bool operator ==(const InfoText &other)
        {
            return (this->shortMsg == other.shortMsg) && (this->longMsg == other.longMsg);
        }

        bool operator !=(const InfoText &other)
        {
            return !(*this == other);
        }
    } InfoText;


    QTime arrivalNextImmediateStop;             //!< Arrival time (planned). It can be found under Time inside Arr in XML reply
    QTime arrivalNextImmediateStopRelative;     //!< Arrival time (relative, @p arrivalNextImmediateStop + @p delay)

    // Departure data
    QTime departure;            //!< Departure time (planned). It can be found under Time inside Dep in XML reply
    quint32 departureRelative;  //!< Departure time (relative and in minutes, @p departure + @p delay - current time)
    int delay;                  //!< Departure time delay (minutes). It can be found under Delay inside Dep in XML reply

    // Transfer time
    // TODO Calculate this at the beginning of the data fusion slotGetData(). It is required for the display of the connection (remaining time column)
    QTime transferTime;         //!< Transfer time based on the CSV L and V files. Required for the lookup filter (see @ref Data::Filtering::FilterFutureLookup)

    // Direction and destination data
    quint8 direction;           //!< Run direction (1, 2). It can be found under Attribute of type DIRECTIONFLAG in XML reply
    QString directionTarget;    //!< Run direction final destination. It can be found under Attribute of type DIRECTION in XML reply

    QString operatorJ;          //!< Full name of operator of the journey (Berliener Verkehrsbetriebe, DB Regio AG ...). It can be found under Attribute of type OPERATOR in XML reply
    QString vehicleType;        //!< Type of the vehicle (B, F, U, S ...). It can be found under Attribute with of type CATEGORY in XML reply
    QString line;               //!< The line of the vehicle (for example: 109 (for Bus 109), S5 (for S-Bahn 5) etc.). It can be found under Attribute of type NUMBER in XML reply

    // Immedidate stops data
    quint32 immediateStop1;     //!< First immediate stop ID (without offset) after current station
    quint32 immediateStop2;     //!< Second immediate stop ID (without offset) after current stations

    bool dirty;                 //!< Used by the secondary filtering mechanism this value shows whether the given connection has been marked for removal or not

    /**
     * @brief Stores all <InfoText/> element found inside the journey's <InfoTextLists/> element. An info text is a message consisting of a headline (short message)
     *        and a body (long message)
     */
    QList<InfoText> infoTexts;


    /**
     * @brief Constructor
     */
    Journey()
    {
        this->arrivalNextImmediateStop = QTime();
        this->arrivalNextImmediateStop = QTime();
        this->departure = QTime();
        this->departureRelative = 0;
        this->transferTime = QTime();
        this->delay = this->direction = this->immediateStop1 = this->immediateStop2 = 0;
        this->directionTarget = this->operatorJ = this->vehicleType = this->line = "";
        this->dirty = false;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Allows comparing for equality between two journeys
     * @param other Journey to compare with
     * @return True if arrival time to both next two immediate stops, departure time, relative departure
     *         time, delay, direction, destination, journey operator, vehicle type, line and IDs of next
     *         two immediate stops are equal
     */
    bool operator ==(const Journey &other)
    {
        return arrivalNextImmediateStop == other.arrivalNextImmediateStop
                && arrivalNextImmediateStopRelative == other.arrivalNextImmediateStopRelative
                && departure == other.departure
                && departureRelative == other.departureRelative
                && delay == other.delay
                && direction == other.direction
                && directionTarget == other.directionTarget
                && operatorJ == other.operatorJ
                && vehicleType == other.vehicleType
                && line == other.line
                && immediateStop1 == other.immediateStop1
                && immediateStop2 == other.immediateStop2;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Allows comparing for inequality between two journeys
     * @param other
     * @return True if arrival time to both next two immediate stops, departure time, relative departure
     *         time, delay, direction, destination, journey operator, vehicle type, line and IDs of next
     *         two immediate stops are not equal
     */
    bool operator !=(const Journey &other)
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Overloads the < operator to allow sorting journeys in a ascending order based on their line. Due to the alphanumeric nature of
     *        most lines special handling is required to ensure proper order. With the default string comparison namely own_line < other_line the result
     *        is in most cases not correct: M10, M5, M8 instead of M5, M8, M10. Using @ref alphanumericLineSplitRx an attempt is made to split the line
     *        into two distrinctive tokens - alphabetic and numeric. If the split does not succeed the line is made only of letter or digits in which case
     *        standard string comparison can be used. On the other hand if it does succeed, we need to do a comparison of each of the two tokens. In some
     *        cases lines can be the same in which case the direction of both is used for the comparison
     * @param other A journey with a line
     * @return True if line of journey is smaller (string comparison or numeric comparison if lines are of alphanumeric or only numeric nature) than line of @p journey
     */
    bool operator < (const Journey &other)
    {
        QRegularExpressionMatch matchesOwn = alphanumericLineSplitRx.match(this->line);
        QRegularExpressionMatch matchesOther = alphanumericLineSplitRx.match(other.line);

        // Figure out if the lines of our own and the other journey are complex (alphanumeric) or simple (just alphabetic or just numeric)
        // If we have alphanumeric lines we need to split each line into two tokens - alphabetic and numeric
        if (matchesOwn.capturedTexts().length() == 3 && matchesOther.capturedTexts().length() == 3)
        {
            QString lineAlphaOwn = matchesOwn.captured(1);
            QString lineAlphaOther = matchesOther.captured(1);
            quint16 lineNumericOwn = matchesOwn.captured(2).toUInt();
            quint16 lineNumericOther = matchesOther.captured(2).toUInt();

            // If the alphabetic token of both journies are different there is not need to compare the numeric token and
            // standard string comparison is used
            // Example: N20, M100 will be sorted as M100, N20 since M comes before N
            if (lineAlphaOwn != lineAlphaOther)
            {
                return this->line < other.line;
            }

            // If the alphabetic token is the same for both lines the numeric token is the next criterion for sorting
            // Example: N10, N1, N2, N20 will be sorted as N1, N2, N10, N20
            if (lineNumericOwn != lineNumericOther)
            {
                return lineNumericOwn < lineNumericOther;
            }

            // If both the alphabetic and the numeric tokens are the same the direction will be used as the sorting criterion
            // Example: N10 (direction 2), N10 (direction 1) will be sorted as N10 (direction 1), N10 (direction 2)
            return this->direction < other.direction;
        }

        // In case the matching has failed this means that the line consists either of just a single alphabetic or numeric
        // The numeric-only case needs to be handled to avoid sorting results like 1, 100, 1000, 2, 20, 2000 ...
        bool isOwnNumericOnly = false;
        bool isOtherNumericOnly = false;
        quint16 lineNumericOwn = matchesOwn.captured(1).toUInt(&isOwnNumericOnly);
        quint16 lineNumericOther = matchesOther.captured(1).toUInt(&isOtherNumericOnly);

        if (isOwnNumericOnly && isOtherNumericOnly)
        {
            // In case the line (digits only!) of both journies are different, we use standard numeric comparison
            // Example: 206, 815, 413 will be sorted as 206, 413, 815
            if (lineNumericOwn != lineNumericOther)
            {
                return lineNumericOwn < lineNumericOther;
            }

            // Both journies have the same number for a line so the direction is used as the sorting criterion
            // Example: 280 (direction 2), 280 (direction 1) will be sorted as 280 (direction 1), 280 (direction 2)
            return this->direction < other.direction;
        }
        else
        {
            // In case the line (letters only!) of both journies are different, we use standard string comparison
            // Example: S, TXL, R will be sorted as R, S, TXL
            if (this->line != other.line)
            {
                return this->line < other.line;
            }

            // Both journies have the same letter for a line so the direction is used as the sorting criterion
            // Example: TXL (direction 2), TXL (direction 1) will be sorted as TXL (direction 1), TXL (direction 2)
            return this->direction < other.direction;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief Overloads the > operator to allow sorting journeys in a ascending order based on their line. Internally the overloaded
     * @ref operator < and @ref operator != operators are used
     * @param other A journey with a line
     * @return True if line of journey is greater (string comparison or numeric comparison if lines are of alphanumeric or only numeric nature) than line of @p journey
     */
    bool operator > (const Journey &other)
    {
        return (*this != other) && (*this < other);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Checks if the journey belongs to a specific vehicle type
     * @param vehicleType Type of vehicle to check own affiliation with
     * @return True if journey belongs to @p vehicleType
     */
    bool belongsToVehicleType(QString vehicleType)
    {
        return this->vehicleType == vehicleType;
    }
} Journey;
```

It stores data retrieved from HTTP GET replies from a server that provides information about various vehicles and their course through the city.

A requirement in the specification I'm working with gives a not so trivial sorting mechanism for the journeys after I have filtered invalid once (based on various criteria) that has led to the bulky overloaded `<` operator (the others are not important here) you see in the code snippet above.

I had to split all available journeys into smaller groups (based on vehicle type, which is what the `belongsToVehicleType()` function is for). For each group of journeys I have to run `std::sort` to achieve the required order of that data.

Long story short - everything works on my local machine (a 32bit Ubuntu 16.04 with Qt 5.4.2) but when I tried to cross-compile it (the target system also uses Qt 5.4.2, Intel-based 32bit architecture etc.). Note that if I comment out ALL lines where I call the `std::sort()` appears my code compile fine even with the cross-compiler (**although the linker complains about not being able to find `libc.so.6` for some reason**). Below you can see what Qt Creator outputs as an error message:

> /opt/target-toolchain/crosstools/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/4.7.4/bits/stl_algo.h:2277: error: passing 'const Data::Journey' as 'this' argument of 'bool Data::Journey::operator<(const Data::Journey&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

This error appears when I call `std::sort` on ANY of the `QList`s with the respective journeys. For example:

```
QList<Journey> connectionsRE;

// Fill connectionsRE

if (connectionsRE.length())
{
    LOG(INFO) << "Regional train (Express) RE1-RE9 connections:";
    std::sort(connectionsRE.begin(), connectionsRE.end());  // <----------- ERROR STARTS FROM HERE!!!

    // Do something else with connectionsRE
}
```

The full compile error when running `make` inside the build folder of the project is

```
In file included from /opt/target-toolchain/crosstools/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../i686-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/4.7.4/algorithm:63:0,
                 from /opt/target-toolchain/Qt/Qt5/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:81,
                 from /opt/target-toolchain/Qt/Qt5/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:37,
                 from /opt/target-toolchain/Qt/Qt5/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:41,
                 from /opt/target-toolchain/Qt/Qt5/include/QtCore/qobject.h:40,
                 from /opt/target-toolchain/Qt/Qt5/include/QtCore/QObject:1,
                 from /home/user/Projects/project/src/datafusionhandler.h:4,
                 from /home/user/Projects/project/src/datafusionhandler.cpp:1:
/opt/target-toolchain/crosstools/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../i686-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/4.7.4/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = QList<Data::Journey>::iterator; _Tp = Data::Journey]':
/opt/target-toolchain/crosstools/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../i686-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/4.7.4/bits/stl_algo.h:2315:70:   required from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator) [with _RandomAccessIterator = QList<Data::Journey>::iterator]'
/opt/target-toolchain/crosstools/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../i686-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/4.7.4/bits/stl_algo.h:2347:54:   required from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size) [with _RandomAccessIterator = QList<Data::Journey>::iterator; _Size = int]'
/opt/target-toolchain/crosstools/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../i686-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/4.7.4/bits/stl_algo.h:5483:4:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = QList<Data::Journey>::iterator]'
/home/user/Projects/project/src/datafusionhandler.cpp:387:61:   required from here
/opt/target-toolchain/crosstools/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../i686-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/4.7.4/bits/stl_algo.h:2277:4: error: passing 'const Data::Journey' as 'this' argument of 'bool Data::Journey::operator<(const Data::Journey&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
src/CMakeFiles/project.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/project.dir/datafusionhandler.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/project.dir/datafusionhandler.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1018: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/project.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/project.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The `-Wfatal-errors` is set for both building for my local machine and for the target system. Perhaps some underlying library from my rootfs directory (where the image of the target operating system is stored) is too old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to declare some of your operator functions as const, such as this:

```
bool operator > (const Journey &other) const
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Obviously it works since I marked your answer as such. :P Thanks!

Comment: Np. Though I'm still not sure why this problem didn't occur for the local build. I need to double check the flags.